# How to upload image to Strapi with Nuxt 3 server?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, multipartform-data, strapi

I am trying to upload an image to Strapi API.
I made a Nuxt server route

```
// server/api/post.js

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  const files = await readMultipartFormData(event);

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("files", files[0]);

  return await $fetch(config.public.api.url + "/api/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.API_TOKEN,
    },
    body: formData,
  });
});
```

then in my app

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", files[0]);

const res: any = await $fetch("/api/post", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
});
```

seems like formData format is changed after sending it on the server.

This request to Strapi fails.
How can I ulpload an image to Strapi with Nuxt 3?